# The number of plane partitions. A000219

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

Here is what is clear to me:  The generating function for the number of partitions of the integer $n$ using one  type (or color) of 1, two types of 2, three types of 3, ...   is $\displaystyle \prod_{k \geq 1} (\frac{1}{1-x^k})^k$.  For example, there are 6 such partitions of the integer 3:   1+1+1, 2+1, 2'+ 1, 3, 3', 3".

What I do not understand is how these partitions biject into "safe pilings" or stacking cubes into a corner so that the height does not increase away from the corner.

Comment: @Somos  Yes.  Thank you.  I understand the first and second comments.  My question is:  How are these statements the same number as "partitions of n  into types"  as I described above and is the fourth comment in the sequence entry.  Maybe there is something very obvious that I am overlooking but I do not see any bijection.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there is no *easy* description of these bijections. MacMahon showed they are counted by the same generating function. Then [Agarwal (paywall)](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-0348-8223-1_29) constructed a bijection. Another version (maybe the same) was constructed by [Bedi](http://www.ijniet.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/51.pdf).